# In Java, is it possible to override methods if return types are respectively a primitive and its wrapper class?

Tags: java, autoboxing, overriding, unboxing

While working with the idea of overriding and overridden methods in Java I have noticed that there is some flexiblity given for the return types of such methods.

Here is a bit of theory:
"The return type of an overriding method in the derived class can be the same, or a subclass of the return type of the overridden method in the base class. The return type of such an overriding method is known as a covariant return type."

Example below supposes that B extends A.

```
Method in A:
public Object some_method() {....}
Method in B:
public Integer some_method() {....}
```

So, we see that some_method() in B overrides some_method() in A since Integer is a subclass of Object.

I wonder whether the following flexibility exists and whether the following will correctly work because of **auto-boxing** and **unboxing**:

```
Method in A:
public Integer some_method() {....}
Method in B:
public int some_method() {....}
```

OR

```
Method in A:
public int some_method() {....}
Method in B:
public Integer some_method() {....}
```

Comment: No you can't. But why dont you try?

Comment: Primitives aren't objects, so they don't participate in object hierarchies.  You can use autoboxing though, if you need something similar.

Comment: Java is sufficiently well-specified for you to be able to verify this by trying it out.

Comment: @markspace: The question was not about object hierarchies. I was wondering whether overriding is possible if return types are compatible for autoboxing/unboxing.

Comment: No, You can try once. why you are asking that.

Comment: @Bathsheba: love the sarcasm.

Comment: It's really simple, just read the part you quoted: **"The return type of an overriding method in the derived class can be the same, or a subclass of the return type"**, so since primitives aren't part of any class, then no.

Comment: @markspace: perhaps i should have eliminated the example, covariant theory all together, and simply started with a question whether return types can be autobox compatible. Anyway, I got the answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only return same type or a sub-class of the parent's return type and its known as Co-Variant return types.

The compiler lets you auto-box and unbox between primitives and wrappers but this doesn't make one a sub-class of the other. Primitives are not classes and cannot be used in the way you have.

Comment: I like your answer. But I think it is a paradox. I think the Java specification should be changed so that the compiler can allow it.

Answer (score 1):

This flexibility is not exists, because "int" is primitive datatype and "Integer" is class/wrapper of int datatype. And "int" is not a subclass of "Integer", while "Integer" is subclass of "Object" class

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're getting this concept mixed up with [overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) instead.

Overloading describes taking a method with the same name but different arguments; in canonical examples, an overloaded method can even return different types (although this is discouraged, as it makes code less readable).

That said...this is legal:

```
public int foo() {
    return 1;
}

public Integer foo(int multiplicand) {
    return 10 * multiplicand;
}
```

...because you're not touching the same method.

In an inheritance scheme, similar code would be illegal, per the [Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4):

> **One of the inherited methods must be return-type-substitutable for every other inherited method; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.**

```
class Primary {
    public int foo() {
        return 1;
    }
}

// no, this does not compile!
class Secondary extends Primary {
    @Override
    public Integer foo() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

So the above would work if the parent type was `Object` (since `Integer` **is-an** `Object` due to inheritance), but it wouldn't work for primitives at all, since they're not objects.

Autoboxing is nice in that it takes care of *some* annoyance of having to deal with objects when we only care about the primitive, but it's not a cure-all.  They're still `Object`s at heart, and they can still point to `null`, whereas a primitive simply cannot.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not mixing up with the concept of overloading. I know that in overloading return types can be totally different and totally unrelated.

Answer (score -1):

For first example:

```
Method in A:
public Object some_method() {....}
Method in B:
public Integer some_method() {....}
```

this type of overriding possible, but rest for two example overriding not possible.