# AutoBoxing/Unboxing not working on return types ?

Tags: java

Look at the below code

```
public class Parent {
    public Object doSomething() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public Integer doSomething() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Which is perfect under covariance and compiles fine.

Where as

```
public class Parent {
    public Integer doSomething() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public int doSomething() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Not compiling. But it can easily transform itself under autoboxing and unboxing right  ?

Comment: Somewhat similar: [In Java, is it possible to override methods if return types are respectively a primitive and its wrapper class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701092/in-java-is-it-possible-to-override-methods-if-return-types-are-respectively-a-p)

Comment: @RahulTripathi Hmm.. I got inspired by my previously answered question :). Tried to delete and I can't delete. Will mark it as duplicate :)

Answer (score 2):

In your first case that code compiles because java supports `Covariance` which means,

*If Cat is Subtype of Animal, then an expression of type Cat can be used whenever an expression of type Animal could.*

According to that the first case is fine.

Coming to the second case,

[`Autoboxing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on.

It's a direct relation between a wrapper and it's primitive, which doesn't mean that `int` is SubClass of `Integer`

```
int ---> Integer  //conversion, not subtype
```